# Unable to use two regular expressions in SAS Content Categorization Studio

Tags: regex, expression, sas, categorization

I'm working in SAS Content Categorization Studio. I'm trying to get two concepts, consisting of one regular expression each, to return a number of matches. One is supposed to find dates, the other a particularly formatted number.

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}

[1-9](?:(?:[ -.])?\d){10,10}
```

The regex that is supposed to find the formatted number (latter) doesn't return any hits as long as the regex that is supposed to find dates (former) is active or not commented out. As soon as I comment out the regex for the date, the latter continues to work again. They seem to be mutually exclusive. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One potential problem I see is your . characters inside of the square brackets.  Are you trying to match a literal dot?  If so, you need to escape it [\.] (Also note that the square brackets are not needed in that case.)  Without the backslash, it will match any character.

Comment: Also, do you have an input string for this regex that highlights the problem?

Comment: What is the exact SAS code you are using these in? Problem might me somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern on the end `(?:(?:[ -.])?\d){10,10}` is the date match portion, it seems to be a little off to me.  What that appears to match is 10 iterations of "Some optional character (literally anything because of the '.') followed by a digit".  First, it seems like you would want 8 iterations, not ten to match a date.  But I think what you really want is something like `\d{1,2}([\.-])\d{1,2}\1\d{4}`.  This would match "One or two digits, followed by a literal . or -, followed by one or two more digits, followed by whatever special character you matched before (. or -), followed by four digits".

Comment: Hi Matt and thank you for your response. Dots within square brackets do not have to be escaped. The first regex is not supposed to find a date value, but a 11 digit number. The second regex is supposed to find a date value. Both expressions have correct syntax. Thus, the problem is not the syntax but the fact that Content Categorization Studio only returns matches for one regex, if the other has been disabled.

Comment: You are correct - `.` does not need to be escaped inside `[]`'s.  Also, I was looking at the expressions backwards - I thought the second one was trying to match the date, while the first one was matching the 11 digit number.